# Who is the bifrost counterparty?

Tags: bifrost

From what I read, [Bifrost](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/bifrost) is like a kind of distributed exchange, allowing BTC/ETH to become XLM or Stellar-based tokens. It also enables the reverse flow.

If I use a bifrost enabled service (or build my own), who is the counterparty? Who is setting the price for my BTC/ETH? Does it rely on a volume of other bifrost users? How popular is the service? Can I see market depth?

On the other hand, if I've completely misunderstood the purpose of Bifrost, can anyone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bifrost was developed to help companies who want to issue token on Stellar (ex. [ICO](https://www.stellar.org/blog/using-stellar-for-ico/)) but:

- want to accept payments not only using XLM but also BTC and ETH and
- want to be in full control of received funds and don't want to use existing BTC/ETH anchors on Stellar.

Bifrost is a web application written in Go programming language. Developers can download it and run on their own server(s). It isn't a centralised service.

Bifrost works like this:

- It generates a BTC/ETH wallet address for each user who want to participate (the company who runs Bifrost is in full control of the funds sent to these addresses).
- When BTC/ETH is received in a given address, Bifrost sends equivalent of the amount sent by the user as BTC/ETH token in the Stellar blockchain.
- Finally user can exchange BTC/ETH token to a final token being sold by the company (it's configurable if it's done automatically or manually by the user).

The price of the token (purchased using BTC/ETH) is set by the company which sells it. It's set directly on Stellar Distributed Exchange using [`manage_offer`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-offer) operation or one of Stellar wallets/clients.

Comment: Bartek is the creator of Bifrost!

Answer (score 5):

Bifrost is an application to bridge Ehereum or Bitcoin blockchain to [Stellar](https://www.stellar.org/) to do an [initial coin offiering (ICO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_coin_offering) or build an [anchor/exchange](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/) for these coins for example.

So the counterpart is always you.
Bifrost is watching the Ethereum and Bitcoin blockchain for transactions matching a derived key [[BIP32]](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki). When the tokens are transfered it sends a matching amount of [assets](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lxn5YXuDWMpX2m9DvKNPHGgZHSG1mviPET_Dm55xRKI/edit#heading=h.ipw1sk4jppwc) issued by **you** on the Stellar network to the sender (anchor/ exchange case).

The next step is to exchange them into your `your_ico_token` asset on the stellar network when you use bifrost for an ICO. This is done via an sell [offer](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/exchange.html#offers) on the distributed exchange (that **you** created before).

These are only the high level steps of course. It's important to note that bifrost has a [client](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/bifrost) and a [server](https://github.com/stellar/bifrost-js-sdk) side. The client is responsible for creating a key pair for the stellar network, setting trustlines and sending the buy offer for the `your_ico_token`.
The server side watches the networks and sends the asset amounts. There are also steps involved to assure tokens are not lost. You may want to read the [Design Document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lxn5YXuDWMpX2m9DvKNPHGgZHSG1mviPET_Dm55xRKI/edit#heading=h.ipw1sk4jppwc) for all the details.

There is an online [bifrost demo](https://bifrost.stellar.org/)
running that you can use to play a bit on the **testnet**.

To setup your own  bifrost instance, follow the official [docs](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/bifrost) and maybe my [notes](https://github.com/alpe/bifrost-k8s-demo#get-started) are helpful.